# Losing data on stripe form submission

Tags: jquery, forms, stripe-payments, modx

I'm working through the stripe documentation and I'm currently trying to submit customer details in order to get a stripeToken sent back. I've looked at whats being sent and the credit card details leave fine however once (what I think is) the token comes back, my form refreshes and doesn't submit data to my database. I'm left with blank input fields.

Stripes submission script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// This identifies your website in the createToken call below
Stripe.setPublishableKey('TESTKEY');

var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
  var $form = $('#payment-form');

  if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    // token contains id, last4, and card type
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
    // and re-submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
};

jQuery(function($) {
  $('#payment-form').submit(function(e) {
    var $form = $(this);

    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

    // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

I can't figure out why this happens, I've followed the tutorial perfectly. I'm using modx's login for the customer detail submission so I don't know if this could be the cause of the problem.

Comment: All you have done here is created a front-end form with a Stripe token for the user's credit card details. Next, you need to add some server-side code to be able to submit a payment request to Stripe, and update your database. https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges